# How to put an INCLUDE into a variable that contains a foreach condition

Tags: php, variables, foreach, include

I have a column within a table that contains multiple ids. I can use each id to define a path to a file, i.e. column contents = "1000 20201" can be defined as variable paths like so...

```
/1/1000/content-1000.html
/20/20201/content-20201.html
```

I have written the following code that almost works

```
$fids = $mcat['mcat_fmemids'];

$fidsarr = explode(' ', $fids);
foreach ($fidsarr as $fid) {
$fincl .= include "../content/".substr($fid, 0, -3)."/".$fid."/content-".$fid.".html";
}

echo "html code that goes above my variable";
echo $fincl;
echo "html code that goes below my variable";
```

**RESULTS FROM ABOVE CODE**

The order of code is messed up. The $fincl variable echos above(before) the top half of my html code and a "1" echos for each file where the $fincl variable is specified in the code. see example below.

```
content-1000.html content
content-20201.html content
"html code that goes above my variable"
"11"
"html code that goes below my variable"
```

Any ideas what is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `include` instruction does not return the output of the included file. Instead, it returns the value from the return statement within the file, if one exists. Otherwise `include` will return `True` if the include was successful.

You are now concatenating the two return values from your include statement (which is `True` and `True`). PHP cast this to `"11"`.

```
$fids = $mcat['mcat_fmemids'];
$fidsarr = explode(' ', $fids);

echo "html code that goes above my variable";
foreach ($fidsarr as $fid) {
   include "../content/".substr($fid, 0, -3)."/".$fid."/content-".$fid.".html";
}
echo "html code that goes below my variable";
```

If you do not want to include the files at this place, you can fetch the output of the include statement by using the output buffers:

```
ob_start();
foreach (...) {
   include $some_file;
}
$contents = ob_get_contents();  // get all the content within the buffer
ob_clean();  // clear the buffer
ob_end();   // stop output buffering

print $contents; // print the output
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation. That did the trick. I guess I need to learn more about how php returns values.

Comment: Yeah the include statement is kinda tricky. Sometimes it returns a success state and some times it does return the included php file return value. Problem is, what happens if you may return False from the included file? It looks from the outside as if the include failed ...